# MySQL + Hibernate + Spring (кодировка)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что в БД записываются "????" вместо кириллицы. Изменил настройки проекта на кодировку `UTF-8`, поменял БД MySQL тоже `UTF-8`, не знаю уже что пробовать. Может кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В строке подключения к `mysql` нужно кодировку прописать. Примерно так:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/database?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
```